# set credentials of twitterstream in spring XD (Error Twitter authentication failed: 401 Authorization Required)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, twitter-streaming-api, spring-xd, twitter-search

I'm trying to follow this tutorial 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples/tree/master/analytics-dashboard

and I'm facing a problem in twitter connection.

I've set the keys in twitterstream.properties

consumerKey=**

consumerSecret=**

accessToken=**

accessTokenSecret=**

and when I try to start streaming

```
  stream create tweet --definition "twitterstream | log" --deploy
```

this error appear:

```
Twitter authentication failed: 401 Authorization Required
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just verified this works with Spring XD 1.1.0.RELEASE and my creds. It likely is either a problem with your twitter account or a simple configuration error.

Comment: thanks .. Do you think special configuration is needed according to my mac os Yosemite? I don't think there is a problem in my twitter account